# How to remain same resolution and coordinate reference after calculation for raster in R

Tags: r, r-raster

```
#####first import all files in a single folder as a list #####
rastlist <- list.files(path = ".", pattern='.tif$', all.files=TRUE, full.names=FALSE)

######load them in a stack  ######
allrasters <- stack(rastlist)
input_stack1 <- stack(brick(allrasters)) 

####### create array #######
try <- array(input_stack1, dim=c(13056, 4846,  2,1))

####### replace -3000 with NA #######
try[try==-3000]<-NA
input_array<-aperm(try, c(2,1,3,4))

####### convert back #######
output_stack1<-stack(brick(array(input_array, c(4846, 13056,  2))))

>input_stack1 
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 4846, 13056, 63269376, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
**resolution : 250, 250  (x, y)**
extent     : -1253475, 2010525, 2211480, 3422980  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
**crs        : +proj=utm +zone=51 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs** 
names      : MOSAIC_TMP_2019001.hdfout.250m_16_days_NDVI, MOSAIC_TMP_2019017.hdfout.250m_16_days_NDVI 
min values :                                       -3000,                                       -3000 
max values :                                        9996,                                        9996 

>output_stack1
class      : RasterStack 
dimensions : 4846, 13056, 63269376, 2  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
**resolution : 7.659314e-05, 0.0002063558  (x, y)**
extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
**crs        : NA** 
names      : layer.1, layer.2 
min values :   -2000,   -2000 
max values :    9996,    9996
```

don't know why the resolution and crs in output_stack1 change. Can everyone tell me how to remain the resolution and crs in input_stack1 after replace -3000 as NA in output_stack1

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you are doing what you are doing, but it suggests that you may want to look at the manual of the `raster` package or study the materials [here](https://rspatial.org/)

With a list of filenames create a RasterStack

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/rlogo.grd", package="raster")
rastlist <- rep(f, 3)

s <- stack(rastlist)
```

(do not call `stack(brick())` after that; that does not do anything useful, but could take a lot of time.)

Now reclassify the `RasterStack`. In this example using 255 instead of -3000.

```
r <- reclassify(s, cbind(255, NA))
r 
#class      : RasterBrick 
#dimensions : 77, 101, 7777, 9  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#resolution : 1, 1  (x, y)
#extent     : 0, 101, 0, 77  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#crs        : +proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs 
#source     : memory
#names      : red.1, green.1, blue.1, red.2, green.2, blue.2, red.3, green.3, blue.3 
#min values :     0,       0,      0,     0,       0,      0,     0,       0,      0 
#max values :   254,     254,    254,   254,     254,    254,   254,     254,    254
```